# Write conditonal statement with an empty spark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, if-statement, pyspark

I need to write a if else condition in pyspark in the following manner.

```
schema = StructType([])
final = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

if final.rdd.isEmpty:
    print('abc')
else:
    print('pqr')
```

But I can't seem to find the right syntax to check if the dataframe is empty or not. The above  final.rdd.isEmpty always gives a true values even if the final data-frame is not empty.

Comment: Another way to create an empty dataframe with a given schema is `final = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([], schema)`. You can use `if final.count():` as  your condition. This will return the number of rows, which will be 0 for an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing '( )' at

```
final.rdd.isEmpty
```

Updated Code

```
schema = StructType([])
final = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

if final.rdd.isEmpty():  # Add () here.
    print('abc')
else:
    print('pqr')
```

Alternatively, without converting your final DataFrame to rdd. You can use len() and first() or head(1) respectively.

```
# If the length is '0', it is empty.
# You can use first() instead of head(1)
if len(final.head(1)) == 0: 
   print('abc')
else:
   print('pqr')
```

For more information on

- **len()**: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp
- **first()** & **head()**: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html